# How do I make my search engine on my site, site specific

Tags: html, search, searchbar

I have already got this code:

```
                    <div id="search">
                        <form action="http://www.google.com/search?site:www.hostelguy.com" method="get">
                            <input type="text" class="field" name="query" value="Search..." title="Search..." />
                            <input type="submit" value="" alt="" class="submit-button" title="Search" onclick="doSearch(this.form.query);"/>


                        </form>
```

And this .js file

```
function doSearch ( s ) {
openDbRelativeURL("All?SearchView&Query=" + s.value);
}

function openDbRelativeURL( url, target ){
//Check we have a target window;
target = (target == null ) ? window : target;
//Work out the path of the database;
path = location.pathname.split('.nsf')[0] + '.nsf/';
target.location.href = path + url;
```

and i am trying to make this site specific... Thanks for your help so far, any ideas on this?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Submitting a form to Google Search Result??

Comment: you're not passing query string to google, your input haven't name

Comment: I am trying to use my site's search bar, so whatever they type in it should take them to google and show results for my site. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys. Was able to add onclick="doSearch(this.form.query);"/> and a js file with

```
function doSearch ( s ) {
openDbRelativeURL("All?SearchView&Query=" + s.value);
}

function openDbRelativeURL( url, target ){
//Check we have a target window;
target = (target == null ) ? window : target;
//Work out the path of the database;
path = location.pathname.split('.nsf')[0] + '.nsf/';
target.location.href = path + url;
```

it now works like a dime. I just have to find a way to search my own site.